# Why did Munkres write "unless one of the spaces $X$ or $Y$ happens to be empty"? On p.87 in "Topology 2nd Edition".

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres.

On p.87, there is the following definition:

> **Definition**. Let $\pi_1 : X \times Y \to X$ be defined by the equation $$\pi_1(x, y) = x;$$ let $\pi_2 : X \times Y \to Y$ be defined by the equation $$\pi_2(x,y)=y.$$
> The maps $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are called the ***projections*** of $X \times Y$ onto its first and second factors, respectively.
> We use the word "onto" because $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are surjective (unless one of the spaces $X$ or $Y$ happens to be empty, in which case $X \times Y$ is empty and our whole discussion is empty as well!).

For example, if $X = \emptyset$, then $X \times Y = \emptyset$.
So if $Y \ne \emptyset$, then $\pi_2$ is the empty mapping $\emptyset \to Y$.
So $\pi_2$ is not surjective.

But,
for example, if $X = \emptyset$, then $X \times Y = \emptyset$.
So $\pi_1$ is the empty mapping $\emptyset \to \emptyset$.
So $\pi_1$ is bijective.
So $\pi_1$ is surjective.

Why did Munkres write "unless one of the spaces $X$ or $Y$ happens to be empty"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem. The statement "$\pi_1\text{ and }\pi_2\text{ are surjective}$" is not true when either $X\text{ or }Y$ is empty, since then atleast one of $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are not surjective as you have seen. Note that the negation of "$\pi_1\text{ and }\pi_2\text{ are surjective}$" is "$\pi_1\text{ OR }\pi_2\text{ is not surjective}$".

Comment: The problem arises if ‘$A$ unless $B$’ is understood as $A\leftrightarrow\neg B$, since when $X$ and $Y$ are both empty, both projections are vacuously surjective. However, in normal usage *unless* isn’t actually that strong.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Indeed we run into a problem when both are empty, but then "one of the spaces" is ambiguous: is it "exactly one of" or "atleast one of"? One would probably lean towards the latter although it is apparent that the issue is resolved if it is taken to mean "exactly one of". At any rate, there is no contradiction to what Munkres wrote in the OP's example. I also feel from what Munkres wrote inside the brackets that he intends to define the projections only when the domain is not empty.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

If $X\ne\emptyset$ and $Y=\emptyset$, then $X\times Y=\emptyset$ and $\pi_1$ is the empty map, which is not surjective. Symmetrically if $Y\ne\emptyset$ and $X=\emptyset$.

There might be a nuance in the English interpretation of "unless", though I am certain Munkres, nor any English-speaking mathematician, would use "$A$ unless $B$" as synonymous with "$A$ if and only if not $B$". Therefore let's say that, if you want as precise a statement as it can be, it should be that $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are both surjective if and only if either both spaces are non-empty or they both are empty. Or, even better, that the projection to one of the factors is surjective if and only if that factor is empty or the other one isn't.

Comment: I doubt that *unless* admits a single completely accurate translation into logical formalism, but in general I’d say that it usually means $\neg B\to A$, though often with a connotation, sometimes quite strong, of $B\to\neg A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Do you mean $A\to \neg B$ in the first instance?

Comment: No, I mean $\neg B\to A$: $A$ is true whenever $B$ is false.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, I see. In fact, I actually meant that too!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott No, wait, now I don't know what I meant anymore. I'll think about it when I'm less busy.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: @tchappyha: You’re very welcome.